# Difference between Intel EPT and AMD NPT

Tags: x86, intel, virtualization, amd-processor, page-tables

In EPT,  The first step of address translation like [this](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/virtualization-enabling-intel-virtualization-technology-features-and-benefits-paper.pdf)：

gpa = guest CR3 + gva[top index]

hpa = EPT(gpa)

In NPT,  The first step of address translation like [this](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/NPT-WP-1%201-final-TM.pdf)：

hpa = NPT(guest CR3)

hpa += gva[top index]

Both get the same result, which one is best?

Comment: There's no difference. The EPT or NPT transformation doesn't affect the low 12 bits, and adding the index only affects the low 12 bits.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.